# "npm install" Command not working with my mobile hotspot

Tags: node.js, npm

when I was trying to install npm into my system i am getting this error again and again.
`D:\Projects\angular-2-template-master>npm install`

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! Invalid protocol: proxy-utl:
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Projects\angular-2-template-master\npm-debug.log
D:\Projects\angular-2-template-master>
```

Can somebody tell me how to resolve this error.

Comment: Do you have a proxy setting?

Comment: No it is disabled

Comment: Maybe there is some proxy set in your Windows environment? See this issue for some hints: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1418